# How to combine already trained classifiers with StackingClassifier?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, stacked

StackingClassifier in sklearn can stack several models. At the moment of the calling `.fit` method, the underlying models are trained.

A typical use case for StackingClassifier:

```
model1 = LogisticRegression()
model2 = RandomForest()

combination = StackingClassifier([model1, model2])

combination.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

However, what I need is the following:

```
model1 = LogisticRegression()
model1.fit(X_train_1, y_train_1)

model2 = RandomForest()
model2.fit(X_train_2, y_train_2)

combination = StackingClassifier([model1, model2], refit=False)

combination.fit(X_train_3, y_train_3)
```

where `refit` does not exist - it is what I would need.

I have already trained models `model1,` and `model2` and do not want to re-fit them. I need just to fit the stacking model that combines these two. How do I elegantly combine them into one model that would produce an end-to-end `.predict`?

Of course, I can predict the first and the second model, create a data frame, and fit the third one. I would like to avoid that because then I cannot communicate the model as an end-to-end artifact.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your problem. What's wrong with calling `predict` without using `fit` ?

Comment: "I have already trained models `model1`, `model2` and do not want to re-fit" yet in what you want, the last line of code model1 and model2 on X_train3, and y_train_3. Do you want to predit on X_train_3, and y_train_3?

Comment: I want to fit the StackingModel only - the model that combines these two.

Comment: `combination =make_pipeline([model1, model2])`

Comment: `make_pipeline` puts one model after each another. I need to put them next to each other and learn their best combination.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're close: it's `cv="prefit"`, not `refit=False`.  From [the API docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.StackingClassifier.html):

> **cv : *int, cross-validation generator, iterable, or “prefit”, default=None***
>
> [...]
>
> - `"prefit"` to assume the `estimators` are prefit. In this case, the estimators will not be refitted.